# Download image from URL and save it in my app's drawable-hdpi folder

Tags: android

I need to download an image from *url* and save it in the app's `drawable-hdpi` folder and then show it in ImageView. How I can do it?

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790544/save-an-image-from-a-url) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875114/android-save-image-from-url-onto-sd-card) code but it's not a good solution for me because this code saves on the SDCard.

Comment: Apps assets can only be read. AFAIK, Its not possible.

Comment: You can not save images to hdpi folder,instead save in internal memory which can only be accessed by your app.

Comment: you cant save on Image on drawable you can save it on sdcard or cache it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot save in the app package. You only have these options:

> Your data storage options are the following:
>
> Shared Preferences Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
>   Internal Storage Store private data on the device memory. External
>   Storage Store public data on the shared external storage. SQLite
>   Databases Store structured data in a private database. Network
>   Connection Store data on the web with your own network server.

more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Yes, the apk file/ folders  structure is create in build time so it is impossible to add a new image to the drawable hdpi folder