# While saving an image from url using download manager how to hide the download manager icon?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using [Save an image from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790544/save-an-image-from-a-url) accepted answer for saving the image, is there any way to hide the circled icon as shown while this process starts.
[image: see circled icon]

Answer (score 0):

There is no methods to customize the look and feel of a notification from `DownloadManager`, if you ever check the [official API document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). If you want to customize the outlook of a downloading notification, maybe you need to implement the download mechanism by your own.

Comment: Hey how to implement the custom download mechanism without using the async task, as I need to download file on the click of the button. So I mean can you please suggest the fastest way without using download manager or Async task or the link to the same... I need to save the images to the particular folder in SD Card

Comment: If your want to implement downloading a file over internet without a `AsyncTask` or `Handler`, I am afraid it's wouldn't be done.  Because downloading on the UI thread is not permitted. If you want to know how to download a file through a `AsyncTask`, check [this file](https://github.com/LittlePanpc/android-download-manager/blob/master/src/com/littlepanpc/download/services/DownloadTask.java).

Comment: Actually I am using async task for the other purpose when downloading to be done, So what to do?

Comment: And how to download the image into folder in SD card using Handler? I haven't used Handler before...

Comment: check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)